# What is the group structure of $U_n=1+p^n\mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the group structure of $U_n=1+p^n\mathbb Z_p$, $n\ge1$?

And how do I prove that $U_n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$?

Comment: The group structure on $U_n$ is just the standard multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. A nice way to see this is to first notice that an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is invertible if and only if its constant term is itself a multiplicative unit (where we think of $x = \sum a_np^n$ as a $p$-power series). Since $1$ is a mutliplicative unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $U_n$ is a subgroup by following the standard lemma on units in rings of formal power series and adapting it to the $p$-adic integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group of units $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is a group under multiplication. That $U_n = 1 + \langle p^n \rangle$ is closed under multiplication is easy. In fact, for every ideal $I$ of any ring $R$ we have
$$(1 + I)(1+I) = 1 + I + I + I^2 \subseteq 1 + I.$$
It remains to show that every element of $U_n$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and that its inverse is also contained in $U_n$. Every element of $U_n$ has the form $1-q$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ mit $v_p(q) \geq n$. Then
$$(1-q)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^k$$
converges (since the valuations of $q^k$ tend to $\infty$), and it can be written as $1+q(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^k)$, which shows that it is in $U_n$.

Comment: Can we prove the main result without using the power series?

Comment: You can prove invertibility *in $\mathbb{Z}_p$* just by using that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\langle p \rangle$, which shows that every element in $1 + \langle p \rangle$ is invertible (since it's invertible modulo $p$). But I guess that we need to know something about the structure of the inverse elements as well ...

Comment: So if $(1-q)^{-1} = 1 + r$, you somehow need to prove $v_p(r) \geq v_p(q)$. Probably a good exercise.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but can we use something simple like the one-step subgroup test?

Comment: Also, what is the order of $U_n$?

Comment: @Balajisb $1$ is the identity in $1+p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$, just as it is for $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.

Comment: @AnishRay $x\mapsto 1+p^nx$ is a bijection from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $1+p^n\Bbb{Z}_p$, so $U_n$ is uncountably infinite. You can't do without topological arguments (or power series) when studying $p$-adics, so might as well get used to it. The rules are a bit different from those in calculus but simpler in some ways (non-archimedean). But the basic approach is just like you would prove things about reals numbers: one decimal digit at a time + induction on the digits.

Comment: Elaborating a bit on how things are simpler in the $p$-adic domain. The equivalent claim of this result on the side of the reals would be to show that numbers $x\in\Bbb{R}$ satisfying a constraint $|x-1|\le1/1000$ form a group. Well, they don't. That set is not closed under multiplication because $1.001^2>1.001$. Nor is it closed under taking the inverse as
$$(1-0.001)^{-1}=1+1/1000+1/1000000+\cdots>1.001.$$ On the $p$-adic side neither of these becomes a problem,  so special properties of the $p$-adic metric must come to the fore.

Comment: @AnishRay Better forget the "one-step subgroup test". It is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

@AnishRay The answer posted by Martin is the way to do this because $(1+p^n q)(1+p^n r) = 1+ p^n (q+r) + p^{2n} qr$, u can see that higher powers of $p$ appears naturally. You cant use $\mathbb{Z}_p$ property to reduce the coefficient of $p^n$, if u do u should also reduce $p^n$ which will make it trivial because u cant say, i will reduce some powers of $p$ and wont reduce other powers. So for closure property itself u need to define the group as $U_n = \{1+\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} a_i p^i : 0 \leq a_i \leq p-1\}$. If u do u will see that all the answers and comments posted makes sense. To make sense of infinite series , u need to define the norm: $|p^n u | = p^{-n}$ where $0 \leq u \leq p-1$, Hence as power of $p$ grows high the norm reduces and there by giving u the notion of convergence of this infinite series. hence now the infinite series makes sense.

One possibility to have group with finite terms, is to take $\mod p^{n+1}$. By this the inverse of $1+qp^n$ is $1-qp^n$. Since $(1+p^n q)(1-p^n q) = 1+ p^n (q-q) - p^{2n} q^2 = 1-p^{2n} q^2 = 1 \mod p^{n+1}$